# Django NameError when using cross reference in ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I have the package named models, and in which I have several models in separate python files. In particular, the directory structure is as follows:

```
models/
    __init__.py
    model1.py
    model2.py
```

In `__init__.py`:

```
from model1 import Model1
from model2 import Model2
```

In `model1.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from model2 import Model2

class Model1(models.Model):
    field2 = models.ManyToManyFiled(Model2)
```

In `model2.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from model1 import Model1

class Model2(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ManyToManyFiled(Model1)
```

The following solution by moving `import` to the end of each file can eliminate the NameError, but I can not import the models from elsewhere

```
models/
    __init__.py
    model1.py
    model2.py
```

In `__init__.py`:

```
#from model1 import Model1
#from model2 import Model2
```

In `model1.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Model1(models.Model):
    field2 = models.ManyToManyFiled(Model2)
from model2 import Model2
```

In `model2.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Model2(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ManyToManyFiled(Model1)
from model1 import Model1
```

I want from elsewhere import the models using code as follows:

```
from models import Model1, Model2
```

Is there any elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: Django is prepared to use a single model file -per app- Is it not possible to put Model1 and Model2 in a models.py file? From what I have seen, circular module dependences are bad in python

Comment: I also tried to put `Model1` and `Model2` into a single `models.py`. In this case, `Model1` and `Model2` are cross-referenced, then I get `NameError` when executing `python manage.py syncdb` (I am using django 1.6.x)

Comment: You have to put the name of the classes in quotes, so django can lazy-load it

Comment: @Alvaro: It works and thanks! But I finally modified the database design to discard the ManyToManyField, which is not imperative.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/.
The ManyToManyField must be present in only one model, then an implicit set is created in the other model and can be reached with the suffix _set. You will have:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field2 = models.ManyToManyField(Model2)

class Model2(models.Model):
    pass  

a = Model1()
b = Model2()
a.field2.add(b)

# Access the sets with:
a.field2.all()
b.model1_set.all()
```

Comment: Totally agree. Might add, you can put the name of the model in quotes in case you have circular foreign keys in the same file